# Rails: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: not executable: 'chromedriver-helper'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, rubygems

I've setup Rails environment two days ago and I thought things were going fine but then when I ran `rake test` command it got aborted due to this load error:

```
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'chromedriver-helper'`
`Caused by: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: not executable: "C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chromedriver-helper-2.1.0/bin/chromedriver-helper"
```

I tried a few things but nothing worked. I reinstalled the gem and updated it. Then I tried to install an older version of it. I also tried to add
`gem "selenium-webdriver"` and  `gem "chromedriver-helper"` to the `Gemfile`

and in `spec_helper.rb` this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
```

as mentioned on [github](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper) but not sure what should I try next.

Could someone help me with this, please? Thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: @doitright Hi! So I'm not sure if you've found a solution yet. But if you commented out the part that checks whether or not  chromedriver-helper is executable `rake test` will work. It's "Platform.assert_executable path" in chrome.rb in Chrome#driver_path.. (C:\Ruby24-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.4.0\gems\selenium-webdriver-3.14.1\lib\selenium\webdriver)

Comment: Same problem here, and not the foggiest what do about it. Right now testing is totally broken.

Comment: @david.pfx I asked on github and I think there's not a solution yet, here's the [link](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper/issues/19). And so far I've been avoiding the problem by commenting out the line that checks whether chrome-driver is executable.

Comment: @Hajar: Thanks, I'll try it. Pretty bad really, I made a new Rails installation and this is the way it came. Broken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encountered this issue earlier with a colleague who is working on a Windows laptop.
Researched and found this thread at Github: 
https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper/issues/19

This is not really a fix but is just a work around suggested by one of the participants on the thread. What we did was changed `gem 'chromedriver-helper', '~> 2.1.0'` to `gem 'chromedriver-helper', '1.2.0'` in your Gemfile.

Steps:

1. Delete Gemlock file.
2. Change chromedriver-helper version in your Gemfile.
3. Run `bundle install`, so the change could take effect.
4. Run the tests again.

This worked on our end.