# Rails: When does chromedriver-helper fail to be executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630480/rails-seleniumwebdrivererrorwebdrivererror-not-executable-chromedriver) question two days ago, and unfortunately, I've not figured out a solution to it yet. So, does anyone know when does chromedriver-helper fail to be executed?

Here's the error, btw...

```
H:\Depot>rake test
rake aborted!
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: not executable: "C:/Ruby24- 
x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chromedriver-helper-2.1.0/bin/chromedriver- 
helper"
H:/Depot/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
H:/Depot/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
H:/Depot/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

**Update:**
So in case anyone encountered this problem and couldn't find a solution to it. Here's a temporary solution, comment out the line (Platform.assert_executable path)that checks if chromedriver-helper is executable or not. It's in Chrome#driver_path in chrome.rb
(C:\Ruby24-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.4.0\gems\selenium-webdriver-3.14.1\lib\selenium\webdriver\chrome.rb)